# LDAP cannot load AD groups

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

I have used LDAP module with Drupal 6 without issues, but now that I am working with Drupal 7 the LDAP module seems to be unable to load the AD groups. I have searched all along the web but I couldn't find any help. 
The returned error on the watchdog simply states "unknown error: 6"

The complete watchdog row is:
ldap_authentication pippo.4 : Authentication result id=0 auth_result=6 (unknown error: 6)

The same authentication works fine using Drupal 6 + LDAP.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Not really an LDAP error indeed : https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes. It's maybe due to the module itself. I'm in the same case and it looks like my groups are not correctly mapped, although my field mapping is ok. Login is OK, and only SSO don't work with this version (has worked with 7.x-1.beta12)